# why is Vuejs divided the page into two sided vertically?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite, bootstrap-vue, pinia

im fetching a data successfully into the page using Vuejs, Pug, Axios, Pinia and bootstrap

but i dont understand why is the page divided into two sides vertically like this

[image: like this]

i had inspected the page and found that there are no other divs than the main one

here is the App.vue

```
<template lang="pug">
div.container-fluid
    h1.text-center.m-4.text-danger My Table
  
    table.table.table-striped.table-responsive-md
      thead
        tr
          th(:scope="col" style="width: 20%") User ID
          th(:scope="col") ID
          th(:scope="col") Title
          th(:scope="col") Body
  
      tbody
        tr(v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id")
          td.text-primary {{ post.userId }}
          td.text-success {{ post.id }}
          td.text-success {{ post.title }}
          td.text-primary {{ post.body }}
          </template>
    
  <style>
  @media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .table-center {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  }
  </style>
  
  <script>
  import { defineComponent, computed } from 'vue'
  import axios from 'axios'
  import { usePostStore } from './store/posts'
  
  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'App',
  
    setup() {
      const postStore = usePostStore()
  
      const fetchPosts = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        postStore.setPosts(response.data)
      }
  
      fetchPosts()
  
      const posts = computed(() => postStore.posts)
  
      return {
        posts
      }
    }
  })
  
  </script>
```

and here is the ./store/posts.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'

export const usePostStore = defineStore({
  id: 'post',
  state: () => ({
    posts: []
  }),
  actions: {
    async fetchPosts() {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
        this.setPosts(response.data)
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    },
    setPosts(posts) {
      this.posts = posts
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setPosts(posts) {
      this.posts = posts
    },
  },
})
```

simply what i want is to have the table full screened but i believe there is a problem in the Vuejs file

Comment: Couldn't this be a css issue?

Comment: It looks like you've put your table into the first column of a grid layout. `#app { grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr }`

Comment: yes most probably ur correct, how to fix it? @a2k42

Comment: @Kakiz no i dont think so because i had already tried every possible solution

Comment: You can use your dev tools to test it out, maybe turn off `display: grid`. I'm not really sure I can give you a easy to follow solution. If you don't know css, and from your comments I'm guessing you don't, then you need to learn it if you want to do front-end work.

Comment: @a2k42 yes it worked when i disabled the grid display from the dev tools

Comment: @HazalKaya It looks like `#app` is applying the grid style and your Vue component is immediately under that. Not sure if that is being done by bootstrap? Anyway, you need to work out where the styles are coming from and work out how you want to design the layout.